# INFORMIXSERVER does not match either DBSERVERNAME or DBSERVERALIASES

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, informix

I have installed the Informix Client SDK. Then I created a simple .net console application referencing IBM.Data.Informix.dll. When I call `IfxConnection.Open()` it throws an exception.

> ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]INFORMIXSERVER does
>   not match either DBSERVERNAME or DBSERVERALIASES. 
>   sqlerrm(database)

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383871/informix-error-on-running-a-java-program) and I can't seem to find the sqlhosts file in the client machine. Also I can't the environment variables mentioned the post as well.

So my questions are:

1. How to create the sqlhosts file and where will it be saved? Will this be in the database server or client machine or both?
2. What are the environment variables needed?

Comment: What parameters are you passing to the `IfxConnection` ? You can connect to the Informix instance without a sqlhosts definition on the client side, but you have to provide the Informix server connection info.

Comment: This is based on the comments I made below.
`Host=10.20.30.40; Service=my-service; Server=db_info; Protocol=onsoctcp; Database=mydb; User Id=testuser; Password=******;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Windows machine the needed configuration is defined by the **Setnet32 utility** (installed with the Informix Client SDK). You need to set your Informix instance values in that utility for the connection provider to work (Informix .NET Provider).

---

First define your "Host Information" in the third tab and then click apply (btw I'm in a spanish Windows machine!):

[image]

Note: The "Current Host" value should be added to your hosts Windows file (`%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`).

---

Afterwards, define your "Server Information" in the second tab:

- IBM Informix Server is your Informix instance name (`INFORMIXSERVER`).
- Hostname is populated with the hosts defined in the previous step (third tab).
- Protocolname is the protocol used to communicate with your server (if you're using an unsecured TCP connection, it could be 'olsoctcp' or 'onsoctcp'. Refer to [the official documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.cpi.doc/ids_cpi_034.htm) to check which value to use).
- Service name is the name used for your server communication service, which should be added to your services Windows file (`%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\services`)

[image: Setnet32: Server Information]

After these changes you should be able to run your .NET application. Obviously your connection string values should match the information defined in this utility.

Comment: Hi @Fer Garcia
Thanks for your response. But I still get the same error.
Here's what I've done so far:
For the Host Information tab:
Current Host: my.host
User Name: username
Password Option: Password
Password: password

For the host Windows file I added: 
10.20.30.40 my.host

For the Server Information tab:
IBM Informix Server: db_info
HostName: my.host
Protocolname: onsoctcp
Service Name: my-service
Options: k=1

For the service Windows file I added: 
my-service      1234/tcp

Do I need to add other environment variables?

Comment: @JeffreyLua, try connecting using another mechanism, such as ODBC: create a new ODBC connection and use "IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER". That way you could discard first that your computer really has connectivity with the Informix server.

Comment: Hi @Fer Garcia, I tried using ODBC as you mentioned. I have the same error as using the client sdk. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: Hi @Fer Farcia, I was able to correct the issue mentioned earlier. The server name and database name were switched, it was my bad. Now a new error is coming out. `Database locale information mismatch.`. I already set the DB_LOCALE via setnet32 utility. When I try to connect using the ODBC Data Source Administrator I can connect, if I use the .net application I get the error.

Comment: How did you determine the DB_LOCALE value used in setnet32? .NET provider connection uses the server connection parameters defined in setnet32, so I'm supposing here that your ODBC connection is being permissive (somehow) but .NET doesn't like those values.

Comment: Actually, in ODBC the locale values could be tweeked (in the Environment tab): you could define 'Client Locale', 'Database Locale' and check if you want to 'Use Server Database Locale'. In my case, the values are defined in this way:
- Client Locale: "en_US.CP1252",
- Database Locale: "en_US.819",
- Use Server Database Locale: check.
btw: Our server is a LInux box.